# getting two lists of objects from controller to view using json and javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have drop-down list in View, when on-change I need to invoke method in the controller by javascript code, **this method must return two lists of objects** by using JsonResult, and deal with the results in the view in JavaScript.

Here is my View:

```
Files:

    @Html.DropDownList("File", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>())

<table id="trTable" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered">
</table>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#File').select2(
            {
                allowClear: true,
                width: 150,
            })
       .on('change', function () {
           var fileId = $('#File').val();
       $.getJSON("/Files/getWords", { fileId: fileId}, function (data) {
           $('#trTable').empty();
           var items = "<table id=" + "'trTable'" + "class=" + "'table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered'" + "'><tbody>";

          // here where I want to deal with two objects lists (Files and Words)

           });
           items += "</tbody></table>";
           $("#trTable").html(items);
       });
```

and the method in Controller:

```
public JsonResult getWords(int fileId)
        {

           var PWs = db.Words.Where(x=>x.File_Id.Equals(fileId));
           var Files = db.Files.toList(); 

           // here where I want to pass the two lists (PWs and Files).
           //return Json(files, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

So how to solve this problem?? 
I need your help

Comment: wrap your 2 list in a viewmodel and serialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can return composed object:

```
var result=new { PWs=PWs, Files=Files};
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: How to use result in javascript?

Comment: You can use result[0] and result[1] for the two lists.

Comment: if you get `data` object from i.e. jQuery ajax, then just call `data.PWs` and `data.Files` (I am not sure about casing, it may be data.pws and data.files)

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution, Code for controller is as below:

```
 Class ClassDetails = db.Classes.Find(clasId);
 // finding the branch of the student for registration and other fees
 int branchId = db.Students.Where(z => z.StudentID == id).Select(z => z.BranchID).FirstOrDefault();
 BranchSetting branchSettings = db.BranchSettings.Where(z => z.BranchID == branchId).FirstOrDefault();
 return Json(new { ClassDetails,branchSettings}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and here is the code for jquery success callback

```
 success:
        function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            var classDetails = result.ClassDetails;
            var branchFee = result.branchSettings;
            if (classDetails == null || branchFee == null) {
                $("#txtMsg").html("Please contact admin.");
                $("#txtMsg").show();
                $("#Things").hide();
                $("#myModal").modal('show');

            }
            else {
                $("#txtClassName").html(classDetails.ClassName);
                $("#txtTutionFee").html(classDetails.TutionFee);
                $("#txtComputerFee").html(classDetails.ComputerFee);
                $("#txtTotalMonthlyFee").html(classDetails.TotalFee);
                $("#txtRegistrationFee").html(branchFee.RegistrationFee);
                $("#txtAddmissionFee").html(branchFee.AddmissionFee);
                $("#txtSecurityFee").html(branchFee.SecurityFee);

                $("#myModal").modal('show');
            }
        },
```